# AngularJS UI-Router - Change state without reloading the template everytime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My templates and controllers are refreshing everytime i go to another state. I dont want that, i want to keep the values i typed into a form in contact.html for example when i change to home.html.
I'm using Angular v1.6 & UI-Router v1+
Here is my setup:

```
function() {
        "use strict";
        angular.module("App").config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", "$compileProvider", function(a, b, c, d) {
            c.html5Mode(false), c.hashPrefix(""), b.otherwise("/"), a.state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "views/home.html",
                controller: "HomeCtrl"
            }).state("projekte", {
                url: "/projekte",
                templateUrl: "views/projects.html",
                controller: "ProjectsCtrl"
            }).state("labor", {
                url: "/labor",
                templateUrl: "views/lab.html",
                controller: "LabCtrl"
            }).state("kontakt", {
                url: "/kontakt",
                templateUrl: "views/contact.html",
                controller: "ContactCtrl"
            })
            d.debugInfoEnabled(false);
        }])
    }.call(this),
```

my index.html structure:

```
<body ng-app="App">
   <main ui-view="">
           ..contact.html ..projects.html
  </main>
</body>
```

My question is :

**how to change between state without refreshing my templates/controllers**.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: how to change between state without refreshing my templates/controllers everytime

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do  that, that's default behavior, for your not so complicated requirement. Instead what you should do is save model value of form by writing service/factory & on initial load just load form fields from that data (using dependency injection).

```
myApp.service('formDataService', function(){
  var formData;
  this.getData = function(){
    return formData;
  }
  this.setData = function(data){
    formData = data;
  }
});
```

Your controller code can be:

```
myApp.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, formDataService){
    var initialData = formDataService.getData();
    $scope.user = angular.copy(initialData);
    $scope.$watch('user', function(n, o){
      formDataService.setData($scope.user);
    });
});
```

where `$scope.user` is the model object of the form fields.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/RCIoggdoFQqhFDXdywpU?p=preview)